# Type error- cannot read property x of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an infinite runner game that I'm coding, and I keep getting the same error that has nothing to do with the line it says the error is on, any idea what is going on? my code is below. I have no idea where to even start debugging this, so even a point in the right direction as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('infRunnerCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function newfloor(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = 200;
  this.h = 1000;
}

var gameWorld = {
  platforms: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 200,
    w: 200,
    h: 1000
  }],

  renderPlatforms: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    for (var y = 0; y < this.platforms.length; y++) {
      ctx.fillRect(this.platforms[y].x, this.platforms[y].y, this.platforms[y].w, this.platforms[y].h)
    }
  },
  managePlatforms: function() {
    var x = this.platforms[this.platforms.length].x + this.platforms[this.platforms.length].w
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150) - 75;
    if (x < canvas.width + 50) {
      var plat = new newfloor(x, y);
      this.platforms.push(plat);
    }
  },
  draw: function() {
    this.managePlatforms();
    this.renderPlatforms();
  }
}

function doDraw() {
  gameWorld.draw();
  setTimeout(doDraw, 2);
}

function displayMainMenu() {
  ctx.font = '35px Comic Sans Ms';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillText('1 button run!', 350, 200);
  ctx.font = '15px Comic Sans Ms';
  ctx.fillText("Any key or click the screen to jump, don't hit the side of a platform.", 350, 250)
  ctx.fillRect(275, 300, 150, 60)
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.font = '25px Comic Sans Ms';
  ctx.fillText('PLAY', 350, 340);
}
canvas.width = 700;
canvas.height = 500;
var playingGame = false;
console.log(canvas.getBoundingClientRect())
let mouse = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
}
displayMainMenu();

function handleClicks() {
  if (playingGame === false && mouse.x > 275 && mouse.x < 425 && mouse.y > 300 && mouse.y < 360) {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    gameWorld.renderPlatforms();
    gameWorld.draw();
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.x - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  mouse.y = e.y - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().y;
  handleClicks();
})

window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  displayMainMenu();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<div style='text-align: center;'>

  <canvas width='700' height='500' id='infRunnerCanvas'> sorry, looks like your browser doesn't support the canvas element. </canvas>
</div>
<script src='script.js'>
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: How about telling ***us*** what line it says the error is on?

Comment: 41, but others pop up i forget where

Comment: Ok, but since we don't have line numbers ***here***, can you tell us which line 41 is? And, if you are getting other errors too, we need to know what they are and where you get them. Come on, throw us a bone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
var x = this.platforms[this.platforms.length].x
```

Array length will always be 1 more than actual available index, since their indexing is 0 based.
You should do

```
this.platforms[this.platforms.length - 1]
```